# Rggobi ggplot like pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, ggplot2

Good day everyone. I have a question concerning **ggobi** and **rggobi** package. I am using R version 2.13.2 and Ubuntu 11.04. I am new to ggobi and I'm reading the book *Interactive and Dynamic Graphics for Data Analysis*. The book was published 2007.

My question is: how can I export a graph for **rggobi** to pdf to include it in latex. For example: I have lots of variables in ggobi and I need to export the ggplot like scatterplot of any two variables or parallel cordinates graph to a pdf. So far I've read that the authors suggests to solve it like this:

```
library(DescribeDisplay)
d <- dd_load("fig.R")
plot(d)
```

or

```
p <- ggplot(d)
print(p)
```

which produces nice graphics which you can use with `pdf()` function.
But neither the **DescribeDisplay** package, nor **ggplot** are available in 2.13.2.

I browsed the web for solution, but I found only that `ggobi_display_save_picture()` could be useful for image graphs but not for pdf. I also tried save display description (tools->save display description) and then plotting it with `qplot()` or `plot()`. But all I get is a blank screen while `ggobi_display_save_picture()` gives a good picture. There is probably a much easier solution since R is changing and becoming more convenient to use.

Comment: Cross-posting to Rhelp is deprecated (perhaps not officially on SO but certainly on Rhelp). Also there is a dedicated mailing list for GGobi: ggobi@googlegroups.com . You also seem to think that ggplot and ggobi are connected. They are not.